# Possible to move a SSL certificate from SHA1 to SHA256 without reissueing?

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, sha

I have generated some ssl certificates using:

```
sudo openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout hostname.key -out hostname.csr
```

instead of:

```
sudo openssl req -nodes -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout hostname.key -out hostname.csr
```

Is it possible to change the hash on the certificate without having to regenerate and reissue the certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.
Since the hash is used to sign the certificate by the issuing CA, the signature would be invalid if you change the hash no matter if the new hash would still be a valid hash of the certificate (because of just another algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

No. You haven't just changed the certificate: you've changed the key that it authenticates.